# Avoid mysql deadlock on simple update query

Tags: mysql, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Im getting mysql deadlock error on this simple update query :

```
UPDATE messages SET seen = 1 WHERE fromId=10 AND toId=20 AND seen = 0
```

This query is for flag received messages as seen when users open their chat with another user.

latest deadlock log obtained from innodb status command:

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2020-01-25 14:19:33 0x7f26cc19c700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 11389580, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
LOCK WAIT 18 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 128 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 952386, OS thread handle 139804764247808, query id 48510845 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
UPDATE `messages` SET `seen`=1 WHERE `seen` = 0 AND `fromId` = 16746 AND `toId` = 20242
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 163 page no 1965 n bits 280 index PRIMARY of table `game`.`messages` trx id 11389580 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 57 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 80156f39; asc   o9;;
1: len 6; hex 000000956b88; asc     k ;;
2: len 7; hex 60000001fa115f; asc `     _;;
3: len 4; hex 74657874; asc text;;
4: len 8; hex d8b3d984d8a7d985; asc         ;;
5: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
6: len 5; hex 99a56737d7; asc   g7 ;;
7: len 4; hex 8000416a; asc   Aj;;
8: len 4; hex 80003e7d; asc   >};;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 11389578, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
1515 lock struct(s), heap size 172240, 14139 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 952395, OS thread handle 139804609726208, query id 48510843 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Searching rows for update
UPDATE `messages` SET `seen`=1 WHERE `seen` = 0 AND `fromId` = 16252 AND `toId` = 15997
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 163 page no 1965 n bits 280 index PRIMARY of table `game`.`messages` trx id 11389578 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 57 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 80156f39; asc   o9;;
1: len 6; hex 000000956b88; asc     k ;;
2: len 7; hex 60000001fa115f; asc `     _;;
3: len 4; hex 74657874; asc text;;
4: len 8; hex d8b3d984d8a7d985; asc         ;;
5: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
6: len 5; hex 99a56737d7; asc   g7 ;;
7: len 4; hex 8000416a; asc   Aj;;
8: len 4; hex 80003e7d; asc   >};;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 163 page no 1649 n bits 280 index PRIMARY of table `game`.`messages` trx id 11389578 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 48 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 8013206d; asc    m;;
1: len 6; hex 000000895755; asc     WU;;
2: len 7; hex 800000010d0110; asc        ;;
3: len 4; hex 74657874; asc text;;
4: len 12; hex d8a8d8aed8b4db8cd8afd985; asc             ;;
5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;
6: len 5; hex 99a5627af5; asc   bz ;;
7: len 4; hex 8000416a; asc   Aj;;
8: len 4; hex 80003e66; asc   >f;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

And the table structure :

```
-- Table structure for table `messages`
--

CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text',
  `content` varchar(400) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `seen` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fromId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `toId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

-- Indexes for table `messages`

ALTER TABLE `messages`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `fromId` (`fromId`),
  ADD KEY `toId` (`toId`),
  ADD KEY `messages_created_at` (`createdAt`),
  ADD KEY `messages_seen` (`seen`);
```

How can i avoid this mysql deadlocks ?anything wrong with my query ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the SQL queries and SQL table structures you have as a [mcve] as well as the full error messages you get. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions. A single query most likely cannot result in a deadlock, you need concurrent running queries which access the same resources.

Comment: You can't get a deadlock from just one query. A deadlock is due to a conflict between queries in different transactions.

Comment: How match record should update this query? Have the messages table have indexes? Please provide the messages table structure.

Comment: `mysql tables in use 3, locked 3` - There must be more statements in the same transaction. You should post them all. Also a composite index on `(fromId, toId, seen)` or on `(toId, fromId, seen)` might resolve the problem at least in a statistical manner, because less rows would need to be locked, and a dead lock would be less likely.

Comment: @paulSpiegel no there is not anything more in the logs.